# Convert string to time clarification

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a string like this: `16:00` and I want it to be saved in my SQL Server database in a column which has a data type of `time(7)`...

Of course, before I save it in there, I need to convert my string in a time data type.

Upon using `Convert.ToDateTime`, I get an error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DateTime' to 'System.TimeSpan'

That is because I am saving `Convert.ToDateTime(myString)` into a property of an entity from my database which has `time(7)` data type...

Are there other ways of converting my string into a format which is compatible with the `time(7)` datatype in SQL Server?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The managed type that corresponds to the SQL `time` data type is `TimeSpan` (or `TimeSpan?` when nullable), not `DateTime` – refer to [Mapping CLR Parameter Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131092%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) for the list of type conversions.

You can use `TimeSpan.Parse(myString)` to convert your string.

Answer (score 0):

Use SQL Server's `Convert` function

```
convert(DateTime, '20:10:00:000', 114);
```

See [CAST & CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use it like this

```
Convert.ToDateTime(myString).TimeOfDay();
```

This will return the time . And you can pass this value to Sql command parameter.

`TimeOfDay` returns `TimeSpan` object.

```
TimeSpan tp = Convert.ToDateTime(myString).TimeOfDay();
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of `Convert.ToDateTime` use `DateTime.TryParseExact(yourTimeString, "HH:mm",<other parameters>, out dateTime);`

Other parameters are missing. Please look into the `DateTime.TryParseExact` documentation. But basically it converts your string to dateTime from the format you are specified.

Comment: Bu this wouldn't fix the error, `DateTime` still can't be converted to `TimeSpan`, no matter how you create it.